# Do half and ushort have any difference in shader performance on iOS?

Tags: ios, metal

They are both 16bit so I don't think bandwidth would be different. I would have to reinterpret the `ushort` to `half` to do the processing in the shader, so I think `half` is the best choice?

Comment: What use case do you have where both would be suitable? I always just decide based on whether floating point is needed.

Comment: I am going to store 2 values: the first is going to be a float normalized between -1 and 1 (I think half precision is enough here) and the second is always going to be an integer value between 0 and 50.

Comment: Why do they both need to be the same data type?

Comment: I am storing them in a texture so if they are of the same type I will just need one read, sorry for omitting that.